# Recreating a nightly snapshot work in progress table with a standalone SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm replacing a process that runs every night. The process adds to a work in progress table to say what changes in status (there's about eight statuses) happened for each open case during the day, and then the end of day status for all open cases or cases that closed that day (so there's an end of day flag).

The output table looks like

```
Run Date   CaseNr   Status         StatusStart     StatusEnd       EndOfDay
4/01/19    DD-55    Review         3/17/19 08:44   04/01/19 17:44  0
4/01/19    DD-55    Investigation  4/01/19 12:44   NULL            0
4/01/19    DD-55    Investigation  4/01/19 12:44   NULL            1
4/01/19    DD-29    Investigation  2/15/19 07:15   4/01/19 12:34   0
4/01/19    DD-29    ContactCust    4/01/19 12:34   4/01/19 12:36   0
4/01/19    DD-29    Payout         4/01/19 12:37   NULL            0
4/01/19    DD-29    Payout         4/01/19 12:37   NULL            1
```

I have to recreate this as an SP that takes a start and end date, and then returns all of the above between those dates, so if i get 04/20/19 to 04/22/19, i get all changes to open cases plus all cases that closed on the 20th, plus what the status of all cases was at the end of 04/20, then the same for 4/21, then the same for 4/22.

Some cases open and close in a day, some cases stay in one status for months at a time.

The tables I'm drawaing from are a case table that shows all current states of all cases, and a case history table that has the start and end times of each status for each case, so:

```
CaseNr    Status         StatusStart            StatusEnd
DD-21     Review         4/01/19 08:44       04/03/19 17:44
DD-21     Investigation  4/03/19 12:44       NULL
DD-87     Investigation  4/06/19 07:15       04/08/19 12:22
DD-87     ContactCust    4/08/19 12:23       04/09/19 17:44
DD-16     Payout         4/18/19 09:44       04/03/19 17:44
```

And so on.

I'm thinking of splitting it into two tasks - getting the EOD statuses and getting all the in between statuses (and doing a union at the end). I'm also thinking I can join the tables to a calendar table and using the LAG function to force it to continue statuses across several days.

I mean the easy thing would be to iterate through the days, but I feel like that would be easy for me but take an age to process. The current table that has been running this process since 2015 has almost six million records, so I need this to run as quickly as possible. Mostly peoople will run it for a date span, but at least once a week I'll be running it for a 12 week range (for weekly reporting) and then I'll be doing a year or two year range monthly/quarterly for that reporting.

Any suggestions?